# Is there a way to disable sendmail bounce notification?

Tags: sendmail

Is there a way to disable bounces in `/usr/sbin/sendmail`?

What i mean by bounces, when you send an email that can't be delivered (for example the `To:` address is invalid) sendmail will send a bounce notification/mail to the `-f` address.

Is there a command line arg or `sendmail.mc` setting that will disable/skip the bounce? On a delivery failure sendmail will just silently fail, give up, ignore, throw away the mail, and move on.

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: @music2myear
Google and `man sendmail`. All i found was a setting to suppress return receipt notifications. Do you know of a link to documentation covering this topic?

Comment: We have the same internet you do. Don't tell us you've searched the internet, tell us WHAT you've searched for, the results you tried, how they failed.

Comment: Ham senders usually++ want to know about failed deliveries.